# SharePoint 2010 - How to print InfoPath form for list item

Tags: infopath, printing

I edited the form for a list item in InfoPath, and when I print, I just want to print the form itself.

It seems when I use the browser's print function, it still pulls up some elements from the page and it cuts off the content if it's longer than the popup window. Also, some of the elements of the form are hidden when I print, so that is not a good option.

I have read that others have attempted to create a custom action that resides in the InfoPath Ribbon, but I have yet to find one that works?

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Would it be an option to convert the InfoPath form to PDF and print that? See [this post](http://blog.muhimbi.com/2010/08/converting-infopath-forms-including-all.html).

I wrote that post, happy to answer any questions.

Comment: I actually thought about this as well, and although this might be another feature we want to look at, ultimately though we want a "print" button to just print the document. There must be an easy way to do it. Thanks though for offering a alternative.